# Java - Why do you have to create a new instance for each backtracking base case?

Tags: java, object, permutation, backtracking

A classic example of backtracking is generating all (not necessarily distinct) permutations of a list of integers.

So for example, here's a function I've written that does this:

```
List<List<Integer>> perm_set = new ArrayList<>(); // store permutations

private void permute(int[] nums, List<Integer> perm, boolean[] used) {
    if (perm.size() == nums.length) {
        // System.out.println(perm);
        perm_set.add(new ArrayList<>(perm));  // why is it necessary to add new?
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (used[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        used[i] = true;
        perm.add(nums[i]);
        permute_simple(nums, perm, used);
        used[i] = false;
        perm.remove(perm.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

The above function works, but what I can't figure out is why `new ArrayList<>(perm)` is necessary each time you want to add your permutation, i.e. at the completion of each backtrack search.  I added a print statement to try to see what was happening, and sure enough the permutations printed fine. But if I just used `perm_set.add(perm)`, I would end up with a list of blank lists.

So why is it necessary that I create a new copy of each case, if the current permutation's state at the end of each search is correct?

Please note that the example is arbitrary. This question is not specific to the code I provided or specific to permutations. It applies more broadly to typical DFS questions. I want to understand why, in general, you can't simply store the end result directly, and why the `new` keyword is necessary.

Thanks

Comment: What is `perm_set`? This is the only time it is ever used in the code posted. Also, what is `nums`? This question is lacking a lot of details and relevant context.

Comment: Yes, it's lacking details because the example isn't important. The example was just used to demonstrate a general concept question about backtracking. None of the variables you asked about change or assist the essential question. I am asking about why the `new` keyword is necessary at the end of each search. The permutation example is arbitrary and could have been any other typical DFS question. And now because of your needless downvote, I'm less likely to get a response  that will help me learn about this behavior.

Comment: Because if you were to just add `perm`, it could still be modified externally. By creating a new list, you can assure that once added to the `perm_set` array, modifications to the `perm` variable will not affect the list that has been added to `perm_set`

Comment: So further modifications to `perm` somewhere down the line could still affect some `perm` already in the list? Is that due to lists being mutable? That makes sense then why a new instance isn't needed when the problem deals with, for example, strings.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the code *as shown* will actually work.  For a start the definition of `perm_simple` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

This will work exactly as expected.

```
@Test
public void testPass() {

    ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
    listA.add("a");

    ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>(listA);

    Assert.assertTrue(listB.get(0).equals("a"));
}
```

This will fail, because the origin list if modified after the copy has been made.

```
@Test
public void testFail() {

    ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>(listA);

    // A, modified after the copy has been made
    listA.add("a");

    Assert.assertTrue(listB.get(0).equals("a"));
    // This will throw and IndexOutOfBoundsException, as listB is empty.
}
```

This will fail because `listB` is empty. It was given a *copy* of listA before it was modified.

Comment: Ah, got it. So it's like without creating a `new` instance, they all point to the same object, and so all modifications will apply to each pointer's reference.

Comment: Correct, creating a new array, with the old array, will essentially create a copy of the array, so that modifications later down the line will not affect the original set. It's not just `new`, but you are passing the origin to the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-).

Answer (score 0):

(This is an attempt at a more general answer, recognizing that the Question is intended to be about DFS in general.)

> So why is it necessary that I create a new copy of `perm` each case, if the current permutation's state at the end of each search is correct?

Short answer: It is necessary because you are going to change `perm`.

Longer answer: Your `List<List<Integer>` is recording the snapshots of the state that are correct solutions.  If you didn't copy the state (i.e. take the snapshots) you would end up with `perm_set` containing N references to the same `ArrayList<Integer>` object; i.e. N copies of the last permutation.

Note that in your example code, the strategy is to modify the state (`perm` and `used`) before each recursive call and then undo the modifications on return.  An alternative strategy would be to snapshot the state before recursing, and then throw away the state.  That approach would work better if you were to try to parallelise the algorithm, or if the cost or complication of undoing was too high.